# How to know whether an existing project was made using android studio or eclipse?

Tags: android-studio, eclipse-adt

I have got some open source projects which I want to have a try. But I want to use Eclipse if the project was made using eclipse; otherwise I would like to use Android Studio.

So how can I know by viewing the source code about the IDE used for the development of a particular project? Is there any metadata in any file which stores the IDE information?

Comment: typically that would be excluded when the project was uploaded.

Comment: Its about source code; not apk file

Comment: yes, exactly so. I config my https://github.com/github/gitignore to ignore any files created by the IDE and by "upload" I meant put into an open source repository of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Android Studio sometimes includes gradle related files. That's how I would check.